# Long variable write to file

Tags: vbscript, long-integer

i have a vbscript which connects to db2 and recset gets long varchar 18000 (contains xml message).
The problem is that variable in vbscript has length only 250.
Ok, i have divided recset to array(50) 250 chars each string.
Then when i trying to pass first string from array to file it throws error.
Because in array(0) string there are a lot of quotes. How can i save result to file?

```
sql = "select message_data from messages where MESSAGE_ID = '5461654648464'"

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=ibmdadb2; DSN=TEST; UID=user; PWD=password"
objConnection.Open
Set recset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

recset.Open sql,objConnection 

if recset.EOF then WScript.Echo "No found" else splt recset("message_data") end if

recset.Close
objConnection.Close

function splt (strg)
dim arr(50)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
sFolder = "C:\jdk1.3\temp\arch" 
Set NewFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sFolder&"\file.txt", True) 

 if len(strg) > 250 then ll = round(len(strg)/250, 0) + 1

for i = 0 to ll
arr(i) = left(right(strg, abs(Cint(len(strg))-250*i)), 250)

txt = arr(i)

NewFile.Write txt
next

NewFile.Close
End function
```

Comment: What do you mean "variable in vbscript has length only 250"?  That's not a normal limit..

Comment: Can you give the exact error message you are seeing?

Comment: Invalid procudere or call argument string:
NewFile.Write txt

Answer (score 1):

@Ruslan: Make sure the file exists first (it can be just a blank text file) and I'd suggest you also update your function with

```
Dim arr(50), fso, sFolder, NewFile, ll, txt, i
```

and add `Option Explicit` right at the top of the file as well.

Comment: @Ruslan: If this doesn't solve the problem, could you perhaps post a portion (250 or 500 characters would be ideal) of the data string that's producing the error?